# Java Class Not Found iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have the following problem .... testing my code through eclipse to encrypt an existing PDF file works perfectly.

However, when compiling my code, when I run it out of eclipse, the following error occurs:

*java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/spongycastle/asn1/ASN1Encodable*

I already added to my project the following libs:

```
<classpathentry kind = "lib" path = "lib/bctsp-jdk16-1.46.jar" />
<classpathentry kind = "lib" path = "lib/bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar" />
<classpathentry kind = "lib" path = "lib/bcmail-jdk16-1.46.jar" />
<classpathentry kind = "lib" path = "lib/itextpdf-5.2.1.jar" />
```

My code:

```
public void encryptPdf (String src, String dest, String User, String filePath) throws IOException, DocumentException {

    / ** User password. * /
    byte [] USER = User.getBytes ();
    / ** Owner password. * /
    byte [] OWNER = "test" .getBytes ();

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader (src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper (reader, new FileOutputStream (filePath + dest));
    stamper.setEncryption (USER, OWNER, PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128 |
    PdfWriter.DO_NOT_ENCRYPT_METADATA);
    stamper.close ();
    reader.close ();
}
```

Has anyone ever experienced this? Any suggestion?

Comment: Try putting "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/spongycastle/asn1/ASN1Encodable" into a search engine. Surprise. That is the easiest way to find out whether other people had that problem.

Comment: Not in your CLASSPATH.  Believe the JVM.

Comment: And just for the record: this is a common problem ... you need to have versions of itext and bouncycastle that are **meant** to work together.

Comment: I performed searches before coming to ask and could not solve the problem !!

I put the snippet straight from the classpath ...

Could it have anything to do with the used version of Java?

Comment: I changed the library versions, but the problem remains the same.

Comment: Please look exactly at the error message, it refers to **SpongyCastle**, not **BouncyCastle**. Apparently you have a GAE version of itext in your classpath before that 5.2.1 version you point out. That itext version is compiled against the SpongyCastle library (essentially BouncyCastle in a different package structure) to be usable on android and similar environments.

Comment: Thanks @mkl ... there was another referenced itext library that was generating the conflict.

I removed it and it worked correctly!

Comment: @GeizonT. Shall I create an actual answer for this for you to mark as accepted answer? Or do you want to create one yourself?

Comment: @mkl You can do it and I mark as accepted! Thank you

Comment: *"You can do it and I mark as accepted! "* - I added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error message

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/spongycastle/asn1/ASN1Encodable

one recognizes that it refers to **SpongyCastle**, not **BouncyCastle**.

So apparently there is a GAE version of iText in your classpath before that 5.2.1 version you point out in the `classpathentry` elements. That iText version for GAE is compiled against the *SpongyCastle* library (which essentially equals *BouncyCastle* in a different package structure) to be usable on android and similar environments.

Indeed, you meanwhile have commented

> there was another referenced itext library that was generating the conflict. I removed it and it worked correctly!